# Create email signature for a team Dynamics crm 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

i try to create a email signature in Dynamics 365 for a team.

when i set the owner of the signature to a team, and try to send an email from the CRM online, and press insert signature. I don't see signature owned by the team?

Did somebody have a solution on that ?